# Adding composition and aggregation on class diagram in visual studio 2010

Tags: c++, uml, aggregation, composition

If I generate a class Diagram on visual studio 2010, it only show the inheritance between classes. How to add composition and aggregation?

Comment: Composition IS aggregation, too. You mean composition and shared aggregation, IMO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, visual studio 2010 support inheritance only. But you can try some other tools.